# I Have No List Of Blogs - Empty Blog Folder Recreating Itself

Tags: blog

I have a main website http://iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk/

And then I have individual blog posts such as the slug of i-was-a-web-developer at the same address (not allowed to post more than two links).

However I have no front-page for the blog itself, listing all the blogs. http://iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk/blog/ just takes me to a directory structure.

I believe it is caused by a folder called “blog” in my file structure. If I delete it, I can then see my blog temporarily, until I do anything such as pressing refresh.

The empty folder then quickly recreates itself.

Can anyone kindly advise what I may have done wrong!

Thanks
James

Comment: "The empty folder then quickly recreates itself." This doesn't sound like WordPress. What else you got going on in your filesystem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to show you is - I have put a screenshot of the root structure on flickr https://www.flickr.com/photos/26455180@N03/30726528423/in/dateposted-public/

Thanks for responding - it has been driving me crazy for a week now!  So tempted to just delete the whole site and try again.

Even worse, when I upload images the thumbnails don't work either.  I can view the image when I try to edit them, but the thumbnails just show as invalid image on back-end and when trying to use get_thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out - I noticed that the upload path was wrongly set that is why a folder called blog appeared. I've changed that and deleted the blog folder. All is working.